# How to Automatically Update ArcGIS.com Map Layer Data

Tags: arcgis-online

We'd like to refresh layers in ArcGIS Online every five minutes with location data modifications occurring in our externally hosted SQL database.  We'd like to avoid purchasing ArcGIS for Server.

Any pointers for using REST to make the updates? Can we update multiple locations simultaneously? Can we push a JSON feed containing changes and deletions to ArcGIS Online every five minutes?

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS Online exposes layers via the [ArcGIS Server REST API](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/index.html?fsserviceedits.html), so these layers can support editing if you enable this in the ArcGIS Online console. This is found under the layer's Edit button, under My Content:

[image]

Once you've done that, you can use the [ApplyEdits](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/fsserviceedits.html) operation on the layer, potentially by pushing the JSON.

You'll need to write the functionality which performs this operation every 5 minutes, eg using Python and a sleep timer (or whatever) and possibly taking the JSON object from the feed and submitting it to ApplyEdits.

You can update multiple locations by targeting different layers' ApplyEdits operation. eg

```
http://<layer1>/applyEdits
http://<layer2>/applyEdits
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen! Very helpful!!

Next question for our readers: Any favorite examples of REST edit forms for ArcGIS?

Anything cool using Angular and/or Ionic Framework?

On the server-side, anything cool using node.js with JSON to do bulk updates, including deletes?

Comment: Hi @EriktheGreat I'm glad that helped. Can you accept this answer to close it off? It's also best to log a new, separate post for the second question about REST edit forms. Good luck with your project!